# Visual C++ object in forms constructor?

Tags: c++, forms, visual-studio-2008, object, c++-cli

In Visual C++ (Visual Studio windows forms project) How do I declare class object in Form constructor so that I can objects methods within buttons(on click events)?

I have class MyClass in .h and .cpp, I have few methods in the class. Included the .h in form.h file. In Form1 constructor made a object of the class:

```
MyClass^ myx = gcnew MyClass();
```

But I can't use `myc->exampleMethod()` in:

```
private: System::Void PlayBtn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
}
```

Help, solution?

Answer (score 1):

You declared the variable with the name 'myx' but you're using undeclared variable 'myc'